# Get group members properties

Tags: web-services, workflow, repository, alfresco, activiti

I need to fetch in my JavaDelegate class properties of some user which is member of some group.

When i have node ref to the user i can fetch his properties on this way for example

```
QName PROP_QNAME_EMAIL = QName.createQName("http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0", "email");
Map<QName, Serializable> properties = nodeService.getProperties(nodeRef);
properties.get(PROP_QNAME_EMAIL);
```

But the problem is now that i only have GROUP NAME, and i don't know how to get NodeRef of the user which is in that group? Any help on this?

Regards,
Aleksandar

Comment: There can be many users in a given group (and usually there are). Are you after the listing of all the users in the group, or something else?

Comment: I need to fetch some properties (for example Name) of all members of some group. Anyway i succeeded in mean time to do this, posting in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mean time i succeeded to done this. Solution is:

```
Set<String> authorities = authorityService.getContainedAuthorities(AuthorityType.USER, p_groupName, false);
for (final String authority : authorities) {
    final NodeRef person = personService.getPerson(authority);
    final Map<QName, Serializable> properties = nodeService.getProperties(person);
    properties.get(ContentModel.PROP_EMAIL).toString());
```

}

In this example i fetch email for every group member.

Regards,
Aleksandar